# Is there any way to stop Ruby from escaping characters from input string

Tags: c#, ruby, escaping

I have an input that looks like `\\some\windows\location` that I need to pass down to a Ruby command.

Is there some way to stop the ruby compiler from interpreting it? On passing the above mentioned input, I see that the string has been stored as `\some\windows\location`

Also, it converts `\\some\new\location` to `\some\\new\location`

C# has a @ operator that makes sure that the string is passed as is, is there something like that for ruby? I'd like to achieve this without changing my ruby code much.

**ADD**
The user input comes from a c# console app, and I want to do minimal work on the input string to make it work with Ruby. What I want is to pass it down from my c# app to the ruby app and make it work.

Comment: What about `<%= raw @x %>`

Comment: You should be a bit more specific where you "have" your input string. If it is stored within a ruby `String` ruby will not tamper with it, but if you put this string into your *source code* it will inevitably interpret some of your backslashes. So please be specific: where do you get it from (and in what form) and where will it have to go to?

Comment: @divyanshm this does not seem to be a ruby issue alone. You need to show us how you pass the string from C# to Ruby. For the Ruby part, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer regarding the Ruby part.

If you want to create a string with a single backslash in Ruby you have to write `\\`, because the backslash is an escape character. Note, that a *single* backslash will be shown as `"\\"` by a REPL such as IRB or Pry. However, if you `puts` that string, you will only see a single backslash, which is the actual content of the string. You can see the escaped version when you do `puts string.inspect` or simply `p string`, which is the same.

```
one_backslash = "\\"
#=> "\\"

puts one_backslash
# \

puts one_backslash.inspect
# "\\"

p one_backslash
# "\\"
```

Now consider a small Ruby program that gets user input, removes the trailing newline and calls `puts` and `p` with the given input.

```
input = gets.chomp
# user enters \path\to\somewhere

puts input
# \path\to\somewhere

p input
# "\\path\\to\\somewhere"
```

It should be clear now how Ruby handles and outputs backslashes, the rest of the question can only be answered if you show us how you pass the string from C# to Ruby.